# An issue with an ARM assembly function?

Tags: linux, assembly, arm

I have a simple function written in ARM assembler. The first time it's ran, everything works as desired (it prints `BOOT\n`). However, the second time the function is executed, nothing is printed.

```
.globl __printTest
.text
.align 2

__printTest:
 sub sp, #64 /* yes, I know this is too much */

 mov r0, #66
 str r0, [sp]
 mov r0, #79
 str r0, [sp, #1]
 mov r0, #79
 str r0, [sp, #2]
 mov r0, #84
 str r0, [sp, #3]
 mov r0, #10
 str r0, [sp, #4]

 mov r0, #0
 mov r1, sp
 mov r2, #5

 bl _write
 add sp, #64

 bx lr
```

**What could be the issue?** I suspect that this somehow screws up the buffer that it no longer works. Write is a function that calls the `write` syscall on Linux using the `svc` instruction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're not saving `lr`.

```
     bl _write
     add sp, #64
     bx lr
```

`bl _write` will overwrite `lr` which then points to `add sp, #64`, so your `bx lr` will just result in an endless loop on the last two instructions.

It should work if you modify your code like this:

```
__printTest:
 push {lr}
 sub sp, #64 /* yes, I know this is too much */
 ....
 bl _write
 add sp, #64
 pop {pc}
```

As already stated in another answer, you should also use strb instead of str for byte-stores.

Answer (score 3):

This function is pushing 32-bit values into unaligned stack pointer addresses.  It should be using `strb` to write single bytes.  For unaligned `str`, the ARM Architecture Reference Manual says:

```
if UnalignedSupport() || address<1:0> == ‘00’ then
    MemU[address,4] = R[t];
else // Can only occur before ARMv7
    MemU[address,4] = bits(32) UNKNOWN;
```

So depending on your configuration, you might be getting junk in your stack if you're hitting the UNKNOWN case.

Comment: Replaced `str`s with `strb`s. Still the same problem.